# What does 'shaping touch' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence:

> Don't despite training. Even you would be worthless without the shaping  touch of drills and studies.

What does 'shaping touch' mean?

Comment: Have you a context?

Comment: "shaping touch" ~ **educational effect**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't **despise** training. Even you would be worthless without the shaping touch of drills and studies.

I assume you mean **despise** (to hold in contempt).

---

"Shaping" refers to the intention of training. Training *shapes* the student, in that it aims to provide them with the necessary skills and make them better (at whatever the topic of training is).

"Touch" refers to the input that provides. (In the context of your example, "drills and studies" are considered to be the teaching element, rather than referring to a literal teacher)

This is a figurative usage of the common definitions of ["touch"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/touch):

- Come into or be in contact with.
- Handle in order to interfere with, alter, or otherwise affect.
- Affect or concern.

It is similar to "touching on a subject", which is an apt description of what a training intends to do in the first place: get you acquainted with the subject matter.

---

"Shaping touch" is similar to "guiding hand", in this context.